# Filter using a for loop JS

Tags: javascript, react-native

i have a little problem that im not really seeing how to solve:
Im trying to creat a `for` loop to check if the letter that was clicked matches a letter from my word (Hang-man app).
The idea is to check each letter and check if it was guessed.

I know i can do this with a `.filter()` method, but my challange is to do it with a for loop.

Now the problem is that since the `If` statement turns true once you put in the first correct letter it iterates an eliminates all letters.

how can i get it to eliminate just the one?

```
  const wordGuessed = (word, guessedLetters) => {
  word = word.split("");
  let remaining = [...word]
  for (let letter of word){
    if(guessedLetters.includes(letter)){
         remaining.splice(letter) 
    }
  }
  return remaining.length === 0;
};
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation of [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)? You need to pass an index as an argument.  `remaining.splice(letter)` is passing the actual character.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the index to splice method code :

```
 const wordGuessed = (word, guessedLetters) => {
  word = word.split("");
  let remaining = [...word]
  word.forEach((letter, index) =>
    if(guessedLetters.includes(letter)){
         remaining.splice(index) 
    }
  }
  return remaining.length === 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using splice the wrong way.

Any way, i believe what you can use **replaceAll** instead if you want to remove all letter occurrences found in the string.

```
remaining = remaining.replaceAll(letter, "");
```

or just **replace** if you want to remove the first occurrence:

```
remaining = remaining.replace(letter, "");
```

Comment: Hi so im doing like this and its working to one point:

`
for (let letter of word){
    if(guessedLetters.includes(letter)){
         remaining = remaining.join().replaceAll(letter, "").split(" ")
    }
`
Its removing the letters from remaining as planned but now im getting an array of empty strings.

Comment: why do use split(" ") ?

Comment: First i get an erro "TypeError: remaining.join is not a function" after my first letter, and even if i fix that ill have a string of just comas

Comment: please provide the whole function

Comment: ```const wordGuessed = (word, guessedLetters) => {
  word = word.split("");
  let remaining = [...word]
  for (let letter of word){
    if(guessedLetters.includes(letter)){
         remaining = remaining.join().replaceAll(letter, "").split(" ")
    }
    if(remaining === ""){
      return remaining = []
    }
    console.log(remaining)
  }
  return remaining.length === 0;
};
```

Comment: Remove the .split(" ")